# Windows 7 "Rental" copies?

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking to get Windows 7 for a machine I built recently, but when looking for Pro copies (my preference) I saw "Rental" copies for sale.

I'm unsure if these are satisfactory and can't find much useful information about the actual thing I want to buy. For instance [here](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=win%207%20rental&hl=en&safe=off&cid=12353548994076982274&os=tech-specs), they have the same icecat blurb as actual copies of Win 7 just with the "Microsoft Rental Rights Licensing" added.

Are these time-limited codes for windows? If so how long are the licences good for? Or is it a monthly payment option that is required once I install one of these copies?

Or is this actually the "rental license" as described in the graphics [here](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/rental-rights.aspx)

I fear it is just poorly labelled (bordering on the misleading) license rights, but happy for you to prove me wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Neither link worked for me. Any way I don't believe such a thing exists. They offer trial periods which may be what this offer means?

Comment: I will just make the obvious comment that there is no such thing as a legit copy of Windows 7 Professional for only £28. You are looking at least £80 to £100 for an actual legal copy.

Comment: You an buy OEM Win 7 at very reasonable prices.. plus I assumed this was a payment structure that I'd not heard of before. You can get Win 7 Pro copies for ~£50 FYI, but seeing the unusual "rental" bit and lower price made me curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General Information**

**What are Rental Rights?**

Rental Rights are additive licenses that permit organizations to rent, lease, loan, or outsource PCs to third parties (regardless of whether a fee is charged for such use) with a licensed, qualifying Windows operating system and for Microsoft Office software. Examples of these organizations include *Internet cafés, hotel and airport kiosks*, business service centers, and office equipment leasing companies.

**Are Rental Rights licenses replacements for stand-alone software licenses?**

No. A Rental Rights license is an **additive product license** for each device being licensed. Organizations can only purchase Rental Rights licenses under a Microsoft Open License or Microsoft Select Plus Volume Licensing Agreement.

For even more information [study this page, and all the links on the right](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/rental-rights.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

It's clearly said Microsoft Rental Rights Licensing. This tells me the first section of your second link says just what it is: you purchase that license to add on your existing licence, and have the right to rent the PC to someone in all legality. Because the normal license of Windows is for personal use only.

Besides, I've never heard of renting an OS. Once the rental times out, what do you do? They force you to format? Nah, that's just too weird, and an invitation for piracy, since it's an OS.

Besides, at 28 English pounds per month, that would be heck of a rip-off, seeing the price of the actual, permanent software.

If you don't believe me, just make a comparison.

https://www.adobe.com/ca_fr/products/creativesuite/mastercollection.edu.html

Adobe CS6 Master Collection: bargain price of 799 $ if you're a teacher or a student.

Adobe Creative Cloud, basically the rental of CS6 Master Collection plus a few little extras: 29.99 $ a month for teachers and students.

Now, how much is a retail or OEM disc for Windows 7? Would that rental price make sense? :p

Comment: I was thinking £28 to buy the OS, _then_ you have to pay X amount a month to keep it activated. After that time the windows validation would fail for the given product key (same as when you use a product key twice). Technically, it is feasible. I decided to just get a copy I knew was legit for £20 more. None of the sites selling it say "this is not windows" they just list the benefits of windows, quite misleading, to me anyway.

Comment: Hehe. No problem. But nope, that's not it. Besides, as I said, it's not exactly a smart move to rent an OS. It's what the computer works with. It's an invitation for people to be forced to format or resort to piracy. And an even higher amount of keys circulating, making piracy that much easier. @Martin

Answer (score 0):

For those landing here hoping to "rent" Windows: There is (as of this writing) a way to do it. You can sign up with a Microsoft partner like Softchoice. From there, you can pay a monthly fee per license.
You must go thru a MS "Partner". Microsoft doesn't offer this directly. It's for IT companies who have fluctuating usage, but often they'll work with you even if you need just a few licenses. I wish there was a Microsoft partner that fully automated getting started, but last I checked, there is the manual process of signing up. SoftChoice is just 1 option. There are many. My guess is big players like CDW may offer this as well.

When I was in an IT-related business, this was a life saver. I could just pay monthly for whatever server license usage I had. Hope this helps.